# What's the difference between url.getFile() and getpath()?

Tags: java, http, url, path

In `java.net.url` there is a [`getFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29) method and a [`getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) method.

In my testing, they both return the same result: the full path and file after the domain name trailing slash.

For instance, `http://www.google.com/x/y/z.html` returns `x/y/z.html` for both methods.

Could someone elaborate on the Javadocs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `URL.getFile()` javadocs say this:

> Gets the file name of this URL. The returned file portion will be the same as getPath(), plus the concatenation of the value of getQuery(), if any. If there is no query portion, this method and getPath() will return identical results.

They will be the same unless there is a query string, e.g. a `?somename=value&somethingelse=value2` in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

[URL.getFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile--):

> Gets the file name of this URL. The returned file portion will be the same as getPath(), plus the concatenation of the value of getQuery(), if any. If there is no query portion, this method and getPath() will return identical results.

Answer (score 0):

### File, in the general case, is longer

```
new URL("http://www.google.com/x/y/z.html?v=1#chapter1").getFile();
// returns:  "/x/y/z.html?v=1"
```

, than Path:

```
new URL("http://www.google.com/x/y/z.html?v=1#chapter1").getPath();
// returns:  "/x/y/z.html"
```